# Simulate a keypress on Android tablet without a keyboard

Tags: usb, boot, bootloader, windows, usb-on-the-go

This is a follow-up question to [this question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1155303/is-it-possible-to-install-windows-10-on-an-android-device/1155334#1155334).

[This YouTube tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16rFXqjgYdY) outlines the process of installing Windows 10 on an Android tablet with an x86-based processor architecture. However, a crucial step of the process involves initiating boot mode on the tablet with F11 in order to select boot from USB as an option, and hitting F11 requires connecting the tablet to a USB keyboard via a USB OTG cable.

Since I don't have either an OTG cable or a USB keyboard, I'm wondering if there's a *SuperUser* (read: geeky and resourceful) way to bypass the need of the USB keyboard and OTG cable entirely (or failing that, just the USB keyboard)? Something like auto-running script on a USB device that could simulate the pressing of the F11 key on the Android tablet during boot for that one instance?

Comment: Can you connect to ADB ... . Or is it entirely replaced with Windows .... .. I had a similar problem with an android pendo pad . it had been updated to Windows 8 by the factory, I ran into some problems and did a factory reset ! .. Nek minut.... Press F11 to boot into factory reset .... My tablet wouldn't respond to a usb otg keyboard because the pre-os windows is only programmed to support hardware keyboards. OTG requires the device to be fully booted and running some sort of driver or built in app

Comment: ADB codes can work ... only if you have ADB still

Comment: I don't actually have a tablet to work with atm, I'm planning on doing the tutorial on a friend's, and yes, I'm *assuming* that once the USB with the Windows ISO is inserted and being loaded, the part that gives you the option to press F11 is the Windows BIOS, and therefore that the ADB and any other Android developments are off-limits. These are all assumptions on my part though, I've not actually had any hands-on experience with an Android device yet.

Comment: Though just from the reading around I've done, it sounds like your information on OTG cables might be off. As I understand it, the whole purpose of OTG cables is to provide plug-and-play functionality for things like USB mice and keyboards, well before the drivers have been installed. I've also seen videos that demonstrate this. I have heard that not all Android devices support OTG without some pre-configuration, so I'm presuming that was the problem you were having.

Comment: Well I'm not sure why.. It would allow me to use the keyboard with certain recoveries, while the exact screen your talking about, wouldn't recognize anything, OTG mouse or keyboard

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my comments

ADB CONTROL INPUT COMMANDS

---

```
adb devices  
adb wait-for-device   
adb shell input keyevent 141   
adb kill-server
```

> 1. check devices
> 2. wait for device to be found
> 3. run the key event of F11 "141"
> 4. kill the adb server

I know this wont help, but i hope it can help someone actually running android !